# $\lim_{ x \to 0^+ } \frac{(1+(\sin x)^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}-1}{((1+\sin x)^{(\frac{-1}{x})}-e^{-1}) \ln (1+ \sqrt{1-e^{-x^2}})}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I have to evaluate this limit:
$$\lim_{ x \to 0^+ }  \frac{(1+(\sin x)^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}-1}{((1+\sin x)^{(\frac{-1}{x})}-e^{-1}) \ln (1+ \sqrt{1-e^{-x^2}})}$$

Applying the L'Hôpital rule. I'm really lost in the calculation and the only simplification that I managed to do is: $$ \ln (1+ \sqrt{1-e^{-x^2}}) \approx \sqrt{1-e^{-x^2}}$$
Are there any other simplifications that I can apply? In my book the suggested solution is $\frac{e}{2}$ or ~$1.359$

Comment: How old are you? You should not be doing this. It's dangerous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, in my opinion, it is better to use Taylor's series. However, if you are going to use L'Hopital's rule, I suggest to break the problem into three more manageable chunks:
$$\begin{align*}
&\lim_{ x \to 0^+ }  \frac{(1+(\sin x)^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}-1}{x^2}=L_1,\\
&\lim_{ x \to 0^+ }  \frac{\ln (1+ \sqrt{1-e^{-x^2}})}{x}=L_2,\\
&\lim_{ x \to 0^+ }  \frac{(1+\sin x)^{(\frac{-1}{x})}-e^{-1} }{x}=\lim_{ x \to 0^+ }
\frac{\exp(-\frac{\ln(1+\sin x)}{x})-e^{-1} }{x}=L_3.
\end{align*}$$
Then the desired limit is $\displaystyle\frac{L_1}{L_2L_3}$.

Comment: yes, indeed I've tried this way and it was ok thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*Too long for comments.*

As usual @Robert Z gave a good solution working with pieces to make life easier.

We could do similar things composing Taylor series one piece at the time and obtain much more than the limit itself. Let me try
$$A=\sqrt[4]{\sin ^2(x)+1}\implies \log(A)=\frac 14 \log \left(\sin ^2(x)+1\right)$$
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120}+O\left(x^7\right)$$
$$\sin^2(x)=x^2-\frac{x^4}{3}+\frac{2 x^6}{45}+O\left(x^8\right)$$
$$\log \left(\sin ^2(x)+1\right)=x^2-\frac{5 x^4}{6}+\frac{32 x^6}{45}+O\left(x^8\right)$$
$$\log(A)=\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{5 x^4}{24}+\frac{8 x^6}{45}+O\left(x^8\right)$$
$$A=e^{\log(A)}=1+\frac{x^2}{4}-\frac{17 x^4}{96}+\frac{739 x^6}{5760}+O\left(x^8\right)$$

If you continue in the same spirit with the others pieces
$$y=\frac{(1+(\sin x)^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}-1}{((1+\sin x)^{-\frac{1}{x}}-e^{-1}) \log (1+ \sqrt{1-e^{-x^2}})}$$ would be
$$y=\frac e 2\left(1+\frac{7 x}{12}-\frac{77 x^2}{144}+O\left(x^3\right) \right)$$ which, for sure, gives the limit but also how it is approached.